# Как называются слова, которые человек часто повторяет?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, значение-слов, терминология

Как называются слова, которые человек постоянно повторяет?
Что-то типа слов-паразитов, но тут важна связь с самим человеком. Фирменные словечки, наподобие "элементарно" у Шерлока Холмса или "антихайп" у Славы КПСС.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что в данном случае не удастся ограничится точно одним термином. Посмотрите [эту страницу](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) в Википедии. Я надеюсь, там найдутся интересующие вас ключевые слова. В дополнение к этому можно посмотреть также статью о "канцелярите".